# What do Kerf, Dado, Rabbet, Tenon and Mortise mean?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for an explanation of the terms.

Dovetail I can pretend to understand, as it is what it is. But Kerf? Dado? Rabbet? Tenon and Mortise? There are of course many more but these are my current concern.

I know what a kerf is, but the name does not match common parlance and to my mind begs an explanation?

Comment: Do you intend for someone to post the origin of every term in the linked page? If not, are you just asking about the ones you listed? Or are you wondering if there's some more general singular explanation for how all the terms came to be woodworking terms?

Comment: What will really blow your mind is how different they are in the U.S. vs. the U.K.

Comment: There are books devoted to subjects like this. I think you need to narrow this down.

Comment: I like the words _twybil_ and _adze_. Definitely Old English sounding.

Comment: A good unabridged dictionary is a better source for answers about word origins than Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks all for comments; hadn't considered an unabridged dictionary, d'oh. and twybil is a new one on me :)

Comment: Thanks for trying to improve the question but I don't think this is better. We want people to come to _this_ site and not be directed somewhere else. Again etymology is a rather large subject. Especially with English words "borrowed" from nearly every language both ancient and modern.

Comment: @Matt your comment is open to interpretation that you wish to avoid links to information outside of this site, I'm sure that's not the case...? Anyways I've reduced the question to be as precise as I can.

Comment: This question still might not be appropriate in its current form since it is a more or less arbitrary collection of terms and the new wording opens it up to simple dictionary definitions. I've started a meta discussion: http://meta.woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/234/49

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Kerf** From Old English *cyrf*, cutting, a cut
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kerf
**Dado** I can't find an answer for this one. But this is an interesting read: http://www.woodworkinghistory.com/glossary_dado.htm
**Rabbet** From Old French *rabat*, a recess or reduction
 http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=rabbet
**Tenon** From Old French *tenir*, to hold
http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=tenon
**Mortise** From Old French *mortaise*, same meaning; possibly from Arabic *murtazz*, fastened
http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=mortise
**Mitre** From Old French *mitre*, possibly in reference to the shape of an ecclesiastical mitre
http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=miter
Now go forth and read [The Debate of the Carpenter's Tools](http://d.lib.rochester.edu/teams/text/shuffelton-codex-ashmole-61-debate-of-the-carpenters-tools).